# Binding WPF Events to MVVM ViewModel Commands in code behind of View

Tags: wpf, events, binding, mvvm, command

I got the below solution in XAML side to bind an event to command and **it works just fine**.

**References**

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

**Button Definition :**

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**Problem:**
Now I need to do the same thing in **code behind** for my object which is a **FrameworkElementFactory** but I can't figure it out , I thought maybe some one can help me.

here is where I stopped:

```
        FrameworkElementFactory newLabel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
        newLabel.SetValue(Label.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.DarkMagenta);

        var eventTrigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger("MouseDown");
        var invokeCommandAction = new System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction()
            {
                CommandName = "FooCommand",
                CommandParameter = new Object()
            };
```

any help please?

Thanks in advance ,
Farzad

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is the only way but you could probably add the trigger on-load by using [`Interaction.GetTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.interaction.gettriggers%28v=expression.40%29.aspx):

```cs
//<Your other code>
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(invokeCommandAction);

RoutedEventHandler loadedHandler = null;
loadedHandler = new RoutedEventHandler((s, _) =>
 {
     var label = s as Label;
     var triggers = Interaction.GetTriggers(label);
     triggers.Add(eventTrigger);
     label.Loaded -= loadedHandler;
 });
newLabel.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, loadedHandler);
```